# Using Swift to handle GZipped (containing JSON) HTTP response

Tags: json, swift, http

I have written Android apps that take GZipped Json data from a HTTP response. Now I want to write some IPhone apps that do the same thing.

What class and approaches are needed to handle GZipped Json data using Swift?

Comment: Can you show the header of http response? If the header contains 'Content-Encoding: gzip', the data will be automatically decoded using NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest.

Comment: Yes, the content encoding would be GZip. I am in control of the response as it's my own server, PHP script that is being called already. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

On swift side:

- **Decoding gzip** - For networking you can use [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire). It is very
  well known and based on NSURLConnection / NSURLSession so also
  supports gzipped encoded responses *automatically*. (I tried and tested this and it works without any extra code). To check if the php response is really gzipped, print the response variable (2nd variable in alamofire completion handler)
  to the console. This will print the response header... it should
  contain following: "Content-encoding: gzip".
- **Encoding to gzip** - If you also want to zip the request from your
  iOS App to PHP (the parameters you are posting to the php file)
  take a look [here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/256).

On php side:

- **Decoding gzip** - To unzip received (gzipped) post data (from your iOS App) use this:

  ```
  // Read the post data
  $handle = fopen("php://input", "rb");
  $raw_post_data = '';
  while (!feof($handle)) {
     $raw_post_data .= fread($handle, 8192);
  }
  fclose($handle);

  // unzip the post data
  $raw_post_data_unzipped = gzdecode($raw_post_data);
  ```
- **Encoding to gzip** - To send gzipped responses (to your iOS App) add below line somewhere at the beginning of your php file.

  ```
  ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
  ```