# How to decode appStore Apple Connect Sales and Trends reports in JSON format?

Tags: ios, rest

While fetching sales reports using REST API of appConnect, I am getting response in encoded format. The format is unreadable on Postman. How can I get it in JSON format.

I am fetching sales reports using REST API of appConnect (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/download_sales_and_trends_reports) but I am getting response in encoded format. The format is unreadable on Postman. How can I fetch it in JSON format.

I used this API to fetch sales reports.
API: https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/salesReports

I need result in JSON format or text format.

Comment: According to the API docs, the response is gzip and this answer shows how to get at the JSON in it (if there is any) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30096298/using-swift-to-handle-gzipped-containing-json-http-response

Comment: I think the link you shared has mentioned decoding data in PHP. I am working in the .net project where I want to get the purchase list in my web application.

Comment: does this help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.gzipstream?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Instead of using decompress function given in your link. I used request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate; to decompress gzip data. And, it worked.